# In Beautifulsoup4, Get All SubElements of an Element, but Not SubElements of the SubElements

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've got the following html:

```
<div class="what-im-after">
    <p>
        "content I want"
    </p>
    <p>
        "content I want"
    </p>
    <p>
        "content I want"
    </p>
    <div class='not-what-im-after">
        <p>
            "content I don't want"
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>
        "content I want"
    </p><p>
        "content I want"
    </p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to extract all the content from the paragraph tags that are SubElements of the `<div class="what-im-after">` container, but not the ones that are found within the `<div class="not-what-im-after">` container.

when I do this:

```
soup = Beautifulsoup(html.text, 'lxml')
content = soup.find('div', class_='what-im-after').findAll('p')
```

I get back all the `<p>` tags, including those within the `<div class='not-what-im-after>`, which makes complete sense to me; that's what I'm asking it for.

My question is how do I instruct Python to get all the `<p>` tags, unless they are in another SubElement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to set *recursive=False* if you just want the p tags under the `what-im-after` div that are not inside any other tags:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print(soup.find('div', class_='what-im-after').find_all("p", recursive=False))
```

That is exactly the same as your loop logic checking the parent.

Comment: Excellent, seems more efficient than checking for the parent each time. I hadn't really understood the application of BeautifulSoup's `recursive=False` feature, but do now.

Answer (score 0):

In the course of writing this question, an approach came to mind which seems to work fine.

Basically, I'm checking each `<p>` element to see if the parent element is `<div class="what-im-after">` which, in effect, excludes any `<p>` tags nested within subelements.

My code is as follows:

```
filter_list = []

parent = soup.find('div', class_='what-im-after')
content = soup.find('div', class_='what-im-after').findAll('p')

if content.parent is parent:
    filter_list.append(content)
```

`filter_list` then contains all of the `<p>` tags that aren't nested within other SubElements.

Comment: The accepted answer by @padriac provides consideration for Beautifulsoup's built in functionality for getting data in this manner. I believe that that method is more efficient, and is a better approach than this answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmltxt = """<div class="what-im-after">
    <p>
        "content I want"
    </p>
    <p>
        "content I want"
    </p>
    <p>
        "content I want"
    </p>
    <div class='not-what-im-after">
        <p>
            "content I don't want"
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>
        "content I want"
    </p><p>
        "content I want"
    </p>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltxt, 'lxml')


def filter_p(container):
    items = container.contents
    ans = []
    for item in items:
        if item.name == 'p':
            ans.append(item)
    return ans

print(filter_p(soup.div))
```

Maybe you want this.
And I just filter the first level p children of div.